# Getting the source code to the client -- what do I need to send?

Tags: iphone

I need to pass on the source code of our iPhone application. The provisioning profile which we have wont work at his side since it was one we made for us. We have made it for his iphone that is an distributing profile, which includes his 3 iPods. And one more thing i have heard that apple rejects apps which requires login... any idea... any experience anyone can share..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the client wants to use the source code to build apps that can be installed on a device or submitted to the App store, the client will also need to pay Apple $99 for their own iOS developer enrollment, certificates and provisions.  They may also need to change the app ID to one in their own domain.

If the client doesn't want to do that, you can build beta test apps for them, and just let them look at the source, if that's in the contract.

Apple may require an app to have some general usefulness even without logging in, and Apple will want a test login for reviewing the App store submission.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the project folder and - if necessary - any ressources which have been referenced but not copied. Don't send any profiles or certificates along, they will create their own.

You might want to remove the Entitlements.plist and clear the code signing identities in the project and target settings, so you won't reveal any information about your own certificates or developer account related information.

Concerning rejection of apps making use of logins - never heard of that. I can only imagine that apps have been rejected because they provided access to paid content that hasn't been purchased in the store or via in-app purchases.
Popular apps like facebook or dropbox are using logins without any problems (and without rejection).

Answer (score 0):

1. Apple does not reject apps which require login!!
   At the most, you will be asked to provide credentials for a test account for testing the app functionality.
2. Your provisioning profiles can definitely work at client's side. You just need to provide him with your certificates and keys. You can export these from your keychain access and send them to the client. After installing them in his machine he can use your profiles for building the application.
3. You can simply zip and send your project folder to the client. Just make sure you have all the resources in the folder. e.g. if you have added an image to the project which is not in your project folder (say its on your desktop) and not checked 'copy items' flag while adding, that might cause a problem. So make sure all your resources are present in the project folder and you are good to go.

Comment: I don't think he should send certificates along - why?? His client is either a developer himself, no need to send any because he can create his own. Or he is on the same team, then the same applies. The OP did not mention he would like to "surrender" his developer credentials, so I think your 2. recommendation is unnecessary, if not dangerous to some point.

Comment: private keys are private for a reason. You should never give private keys or certificates to third parties. And by saying `should` I mean "it's against the agreement you signed with apple"

Comment: Sending certs and keys to the client is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send provisioning profile, along with the source ode.

And regarding the other question, I dont think that Apple rejects apps which requires login.

Comment: No, he doesn't need to send provisioning profiles. If you download some sample project from the www, you don't need a profle either. A profile would be necessary for a build only, not for the source.

Comment: @Toastor: If I not mistaken, I think, he wants to send the source code to the person, so that the third person can install it and test it on his device, as the provisioning profile has already having the UDIDs of the third person :)

Comment: the provisioning profile is useless if the client has the source code. The provisioning profile only works with an app that was signed with the certificate assigned to the provisioning profile. And he is not allowed to give this certificate to the client.